# how hardhat run function works?

Tags: hardhat

I am reading this code from Patrick Collins' tutorial

```
const { run } = require("hardhat")

const verify = async (contractAddress, args) => {
    console.log("Verifying contract...")
    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAddress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("Already verified!")
        } else {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    verify,
}
```

It works, but I cannot find where "verify:verify" is implemented. (line 6)

I checked Hardhat doc. I couldn't find any reference to the run( ) function.

Thank you

Comment: verify:verify is actually a task defined in hardhat-etherscan-verify. https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan. But I'd like to know what other things like this are available or defined.

Answer (score 0):

The "verify:verify" is hardhat internal and is the way you tell hardhat to verify the code.

As dev you don't have to implement this function

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you @donoso. Is there a document about all the internal commands?